# Error after Restarting Server of my site

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am getting an error when I restart the server of my [site](http://paperbase.in).

I tried the command `define('DB_NAME', 'abcwordpress');` to resolve the problem, and it gets done most of the time.

Error After Executing above command but this time I get a new error

> Database files are missing

But I didn't delete or didn't make any changes in any database related files. So help to solve these errors. I am new to web development and I am using WordPress, PHP, MySQL.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question lacks some details. Please add what error you get, what Wordpress, MySQL and HTTPD server version you're using, what plugins you use and what you've done prior its first appearance (e.g. installing something or updating to a newer version).

Comment: I don't see any error when loading your site?